# How do I get Haml to stop from evaluating #{var} values inside <pre> <code> tags?

Tags: ruby, string, syntax, haml, coderay

I'm using CodeRay and Haml to do syntax highlighting on some pages, and I write a lot of Ruby code. The problem is when I have something like this:

```
%pre
  %code.language-ruby
    :preserve
      def hello(name)
        puts "Hello #{name}!" 
      end
```

I keep getting errors because Haml keeps trying to evaluate the `name` variable inside the string, the `#{var}` syntax is a pretty common idiom in Ruby code and there aremany places where it is used, but I cannot use syntax highlighting of those codes because Haml wants to evaluate those variables inside the string.

Is there a way to tell Haml to not do that in some places?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to upvote answers that you find useful (including answers to others' questions.) And check (accept) the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell Haml to not do that in some places?

By escaping the `#`:

```
puts "Hello \#{name}!"
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! Stupid me tried escaping everything else apart from the '#'. Now it's all running smoothly and even colored better.

Comment: You're welcome. Typically we show our thanks on Stack Overflow by upvoting and/or [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I know that and I tried, but I need 15 reputation to upvote you. If anyone reads this please upvote for me :D (accept answer in 3 mins).

Comment: Ty, I just gained enough rep thanx to you to upvote @meagar :D